# Extracting a number that occurs after a specific word from a longer text/file

Tags: java, string, file

I have a text file of `5631` lines. I want to extract and store the number which appears after the word **bytes at**

Sample line form middle of the file is below :

```
debug3: In write loop, ack for 1606 32768 bytes at 52527104
```

Here I want the value `52527104`. Each line this value increases and my goal is to calculate the percent completion based on each lines value. By using the formula `((obtained*100)/total)`.

Thanks.

Comment: In this specific case you can just do `String[] splits = string.split(" ");` and to access it, `splits[splits.length-1];`.

Comment: Is every line of this format, or only some of them?

Comment: Are you forced to use java? There are a number of unix command line tools that would be far better for this specific case

Comment: Some of them. I am concern only when "byte at" occurs.

Comment: As I am beginner to unix it could be a mess. But any help will be highly appreciated. @DiegoMartinoia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply split the read lines by **bytes at** and use the value at index `1`. I have used `Long` parser, you can use `Integer` as per your requirement. The code will ignore lines, which doesn't contain the pattern provided.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BytesAt {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    while (read.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = read.nextLine();
      String parts[] = line.split("bytes at");
      if(parts.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("Value as String: " + parts[1].trim());
        System.out.println("Value as Long: " + Long.parseLong(parts[1].trim()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Keppil Thanks. I missed it.

Comment: @s-das updated with a conditional check, to handle other lines of the file which doesn't contain pattern.

Comment: This answer is correct only if `bytes at %NUMBER%` appears at the end of the line.`read.hasNextLine()` is more suitable.

Comment: @TAsk Thanks. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
long totalBytes = //Whatever source.
long currValue = 0;
for (String line: lines) {
  if (line.contains("bytes at")) {
    long currValue = Long.parseLong(line.split("bytes at\\s")[1]);
  }
  System.out.println("Completed % = "+(float)(currValue/totalBytes*100);
}
```